# How to select all element with specific value and update the value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select all input elements with a specific value that the user enters on runtime in the input field and update the value on click of a button here is what I tried to accomplish this.

```
<input type="text" class="test" >
<button>
check value
</button>

var button = $("button")

button.on("click", function(){
      $("input[value='10']").val("100");
})
```

But its not working [here is link to the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3xLw4jd/3/).

Comment: If your `<input>` element doesn't have a `value` attribute of `10` then the attribute-selector won't match that `<input>` element. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I thought inputing value at run time manipulates value attribute, all i was trying to do was enter values at runtime and then check and replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is `.each()`

```
button.on("click", function(){
   $("input").each(function() {
      if($(this).val() == "10") {
          $(this).val("100");
        } 
   });
});
```

This loops through all inputs and sets the value to 100 of those with value 10

the `"[value='myValue']"` selector refers only to the initial attribute value of the input

Comment: I thought this can be accomplished using just $("input[value='10']").val("100");

Comment: This problem in no way requires the use of `each()`, the `val()` method iterates over every element found by the selector (which, in the case of this question, is none) to which it is chained.

Comment: @DavidThomas The OP requires to set the value to 100 of only those inputs with a *current* value of 10, no matter the attribute. The OP also sort-of accepted this answer with a now deleted comment .

Comment: I don't see how your clarification changes my assertions.

Comment: I mean to say a selector will not suffice if the contents of the input are changed @DavidThomas

Comment: yes I want to input value at runtime using input tag and then perform find replace, it was not documented in jqyery api that "[value='myValue']" only works for the initial value, i had been banging my head since hours to resolve the issue, comes out its not possible at all using jquery selector.

PS: I HAVE NO IDEA WHERE MY COMMENT GONE (DELETED)

Comment: I have up voted this answer because I believe if someone else ever try to do some find replace using jquery selector will end up hear.  That is what I have to do now ditching the selector and using loops and condition to the find replace thing.

Answer (score 1):

`$("input[value='10']")` is a attribute selector. Putting some value does not set the value attribute.

To make that work you can set the attribute with `attr()` explicitly:

```js
var button = $("button");
$("input[type=text]").on('input', function(){
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});

button.on("click", function(){
  $("input[value='10']").val('100');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="test">
<input type="text" class="test">
<button>
check value
</button>
```

Comment: yes this will save a whole each loop every time i want to do some find replace

Comment: its quite confusing that changing the value of input field do change the DOM object value property
`$("input")[0].value`

Comment: @RishabhGusain, my answer illustrate why the value attribute is not working and possible solution using that:)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all inputs with the current value of 10, but your input doesn't have a current value. Set it to 10 and it should work:

```
<input value="10" type="text" class="test" >
```

Comment: I want to input value in runtime

Comment: @Rishabh: this answer explains what the problem is, and shows how to correct it. If you want to select all elements that have a value of `10`, then those elements must have a value attribute that is equal to `10` otherwise they won't be selected with the attribute-equals selector. If you edit your question to explain the problem you're trying to solve then that might help you get answers that are useful to your situation.